# Word that describes a collection of goals

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I have a list of goals, and I need a word that would best describe it. A person would need to complete work on these goals to achieve their overall goal. E.g., "weight loss" would be a main goal, with "work out", "eating right", etc. being the goals that are part of "weight loss".

Comment: What's wrong with the "main goal" and "overall goal" you just used yourself?

Comment: Looking for a one word specifically. Kind of like "initiatives"

Comment: I'd say "mission".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thesaurus: *[target](http://oaadonline.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/goal)***

**objective goal object end**
These are all words for something that you are trying to achieve.
**target** a result that you try to achieve: *Set targets that you can reasonably hope to achieve. sales targets*
**objective** (somewhat formal) something that you are trying to achieve: *What are the objectives of this project?*
**goal** something that you hope to achieve: *He continued to pursue his goal of becoming an actor.*

While these definitions themselves do not give a very clear distinction, it seems the word *goal* is not limited to a single unit (a certain target), so that *goal* is no less a hypernym itself.

***A person would need to complete work on all of these to achieve their goal***.
Or better still,
***A person would need to *accomplish* all of these to achieve their goal***.

By the way, "*work out*", "*eating right*", etc. are not *goals* or *objectives* they are *means* to achieve the goal ("weight loss"). You must use appropriate sub-tasks instead. The example is not suitable for the question.

Comment: Target is better. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

Plan, program, project, outline, strategy, stratagem, agenda, schedule, objectives, calendar, etc. Take [your pick](http://thesaurus.com/browse/plan).

Depending on your goals, [bucket list](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bucket%20list) might also be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Often a group of activities that lead to an overall goal are referred to as *tasks*, or possibly *tactics*.  See this [discussion](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16710651/Objective-Goal-Task-Tactics-and-Strategy).

Comment: Thanks. Would "Objectives" be a collection of "goals"? Would that be a valid? hmm..I like objective.

Answer (score 1):

It has been already given as an option and you, in a comment, had said you liked this word: objectives

[Definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/objective?q=objective):

> *noun*:
>
> thing aimed at or sought; a goal

If you really like this word in particular, then go for it. It fits nicely for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are various terms used in strategic planning, but you'll often see completion of *objectives* leads to the achievement of the *goal*.

You could also use *strategy* (as suggested by coleopterist) or *[strategic plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_planning)* itself.